# how to implement iphone calendar day view

Tags: iphone, view, calendar

Does anyone know how to implement a view similar to the iphone calendar day view?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Maybe you can give calendar-ui a try: http://github.com/muhku/calendar-ui

Comment: Hey, nice work, muhku.  This would have been exactly what I was looking for in January. I will bookmark this for future apps I am working on.

Answer (score 0):

The day view appears to be just a scroll view with a couple of subviews, one for each event. Are you trying to learn how to implement this, given pre-existing data, or are you trying to get access to the actual calendar data on the phone (which is not possible on non-Jailbroken devices)?

Comment: Thanks, Ben. I need to add a calendar daily view to my project, and I was hoping someone else had implemented this and made it available. Seem like a lot of people would benefit from this. After a little more poking around, it does look pretty straightforward to implement